# How to delete dynamic table elements in jsp? What should I write in my controller?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

Here is my JSP Page. Here table is generated dynamically. There is a delete button against each entry. How should I code to delete, whenever I click on any delete button?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>View & Delete Restaurant</title>
<jsp:include page="headerAdmin.jsp" />
</head>
<body>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty restaurantList}">
<h5>Following restaurants are listed in the application:</h5>
    <table border="2">
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Zip</th><th>Cuisine</th></tr>
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${restaurantList}">
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">${o.restaurantId}</td>
                <td width="20%">${o.restaurantName}</td>
                <td width="20%">${o.address}</td>
                <td width="20%">${o.pincode}</td>   
                <td width="20%">${o.cuisine}</td>
                <td width="20%"><input type="button" value="Delete From List" name="DeleteFromList" /></td> 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>There are no restaurants to be deleted from list</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[My JSP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1FZb.png)

Answer (score 0):

To delete the row from DOM you can use JavaScript, add the following

```
<script>
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>
```

You need to provide an ID to the `<table>` element to get the table in JS.(For ex. `"myTable"` -  or use `getElementByTagName`).
And the cell can be added as follows

```
<td width="20%"><input type="button" value="Delete From List" name="DeleteFromList"  onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
```

Comment: And how does it reflects into the database table?

Comment: the answer you gave is deleting the row in jsp page only... on refreshing the page the row again persists. That means, it is not being deleted from database.

Comment: Thats what I said-It only removes from DOM. How are you populating the `restaurantList`?. In order to persist the changes you should hit the `restaurantList` at your back end on delete.